# unsure how to add bloginfo reference to images inside wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` inside my wordpress loop to reference an image but unsure how to do this. My image code is as follows:

```
<?php
      if (is_category('Events')) {
        echo '<img src="http://localhost/mmj/wp-content/themes/child-theme/img/live-banner.jpg" class="live-holder-img" />';
      } else if (is_category('News')) {
       echo '<img src="http://localhost/mmj/wp-content/themes/child-theme/img/live-banner.jpg" class="live-holder-img" />';
      } else {
        echo '<img src="" class="default" />';
    } ?>
```

I would rather replace `http://localhost/mmj/wp-content/themes/child-theme` with `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` but Im aware that I cant include `<?php` inside `<?php` so I was wondering how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/img/live-banner.jpg" class="live-holder-img" />';
```

Full code :

```
<?php
      if (is_category('Events')) {
        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/img/live-banner.jpg" class="live-holder-img" />';
      } else if (is_category('News')) {
       echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/img/live-banner.jpg" class="live-holder-img" />';
      } else {
        echo '<img src="" class="default" />';
    } ?>
```

In shortly,
I'm using `get_bloginfo()` instead of `bloginfo()` for getting stylesheet directory, not printing out. And then using it like this :

```
echo 'Some strings here ' . get_bloginfo() . ' another strings';
```